# What Material Would A flexible Human Mech suit be reinforced with?

Tags: weapons, armors

So imagine a world with no USA, no Russia, and the rest of the world is split into two people/races Enders, and Humans.

Enders look like humans and can be born from humans (due to a genetic defect in their Chromosomes) they look like humans until the 'awakening' which is when their powers are released with extraordinary power and usually happens in moments of high tension. Now the point of this is that the government traps Enders and either experiments on them or turns them into soldiers so humans in the army needed to bulk up so they are actually somewhat useful.

Bringing me to the point of a mechanized suit that improves a human capabilities so they can be as good as the Enders. I would like to know if a nano fiber weave underneath a suit of pure carbon armor would practical. If not, I would need suggestions for a material that is strong and lightweight and could cover up most of the body.

(The limits of this world: the armor itself would have to run out of energy if you over-used it, it needs to be fast but not as overpowered as to beat an Ender easily)

**Enders What are they?**

There are three types of Enders:

- one uses speed (can pierce the sound barrier)
- another type is one that uses electricity and can shock people within 30 feet of them
- the last type is one that can summon weapons (they harness the power of a demon that takes a form of their specialized weapon)

**For the Armor itself**

I have done some research and a type of research that is being pioneered right now that takes atoms and forms them into special shapes and could eventually be used to make a very powerful metal that is created with very strong Ionic bonds and could be used to build a Stable 'Space Tower'

If the nano weave would just be that type of Carbon wrapped around itself multiple times making a chain mail like material any ideas on what I should use for the outer plating?

Comment: Not a full answer to your question, but the following video goes into some scientific details about sub-dermal graphene armor, and might help give you some ideas: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsE10pSYBos

Comment: Is there and Ender resistance movement?

Comment: yes, that is why I need the armor so that the human could actually stand a chance against the Enders. the Government itself is basically Anti Ender.

Comment: @Liesmith nice. Same youtuber batman vs superman without cryptonite https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9m-kjmxsZms Have suite that beats superman - i think thats enough to beat anyone

Comment: Haha I knew I would see matpat's videos (game theory and film theory) in these comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Best Real World Solution: Metal Foam**

The most cutting edge solution for the plating of body armor is metal foam. Observe video of an armor-piercing bullet shattering against metal foam here:

http://www.sciencefriday.com/segments/for-your-protection-a-new-kind-of-metal/

**Best Sci-Fi Solution: Graphene Nanobots**

The most adaptable solution for the "fabric underclothes" would be nanobots that react to dynamic situations/environments. Read a sci-fi discussion about nanobots made of graphene here:

http://www.futuretimeline.net/forum/topic/8666-nanobot-body-armour/

Answer (score 2):

You should consider **spider silk**. It is extremely strong but also super lightweight. In our world the problem is just the syntheses which is actually beeing researched by NASA, armor industries and other big companies.

Anyway spider silk should work pretty good. You can even modify it to be used as a *full body suit* which is electric resistant and it also can be used to catch the super fast enders.

I'm not talking about spiders as a core part of your world. I just mean synthetic spider silk.