# if someone was stabbed in the heart is there a chance to be saved?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency

This question is related to my new Story somewhere in the plot a man is going to be stabbed directly into the chest in a fight , I would like to know how could he survive if the injury penetrate the heart.. also i would like to know if there is a specific part of the heart is more save to be injured and how much time he got before he bleed out and arrive to ER

Comment: Hi! Maybe this question would be better suited for the [medical science](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) stack. Also have a look at [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/41717/44800). Also a quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=stab+in+heart+survive) will give interesting results.

Comment: I'm not quickly finding any sources online so I cannot make a good answer, but I have heard of people being stabbed or shot in the heart and surviving. All such survivors probably got to medical help very fast though.

Comment: Might not survive, but if he’s called Phil Coulson then there’s options...

Comment: This question isn't really about worldbuilding because it does not take place in a universe/world that is fundamentally different than our own.

Answer (score 6):

To the best of my knowledge it is not always totally impossible to survive wounds to the heart.

Here is a link to a somewhat similar question that I asked.

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41268/how-dangerous-is-removing-a-weapon-from-a-heart-wound[1](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41268/how-dangerous-is-removing-a-weapon-from-a-heart-wound)

Here is a link to a question about surviving being shot in the heart.

https://www.quora.com/Can-you-survive-a-gunshot-to-the-heart [2](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-survive-a-gunshot-to-the-heart)

The answers say that the probability of surviving is very low but higher under some circumstances than others.

This articles gives medical case histories of two gunshot wounds to the heart:

http://jpma.org.pk/full_article_text.php?article_id=7144 [3](http://jpma.org.pk/full_article_text.php?article_id=7144)

Here are some answers to a question about surviving stab wounds to the heart, showing that it is possible with swift and good surgical care.

https://www.quora.com/Can-a-person-survive-being-stabbed-in-the-heart-If-so-how [4](https://www.quora.com/Can-a-person-survive-being-stabbed-in-the-heart-If-so-how)

So the consensus seems to be that the majority of wounds to the heart are fatal but in some cases survival is a possibility and some people shot or stabbed in the heart have been saved by surgery.

Comment: *"Here is a link to a question about surviving being shot in the heart."* https://youtu.be/KrZHPOeOxQQ